# jQuery: Can read loose text but not update it properly

Tags: jquery, html

So I've got table cells such as:

```
<td class="right footerCell">
    $51,888,734.24
    <div class="fht-cell" style="width: 128px;"></div>
</td>
```

I know that the text could be inside the div, but this markup is partly generated by a plugin. At times, I want to update the amount inside the cell without affecting the div (which the plugin is using to make the cell have a specific width). I'm currently able to match the text element that needs updating, I can even read the proper value, but when I try to change it, it simply does not. I'm using something like this:

```
//selects one of the cells above at a specific column
var totalCell = $("div.fht-fixed-body div.fht-tfoot table.fht-table tr > td.right.footerCell:nth-child(" + childNumber + ")");

//prints out $51,888,734.24
console.log($(totalCell).contents().eq(0).text());

$(totalCell).contents().eq(0).text("VALUE HAS BEEN CHANGED FOREVER!");

//prints out $51,888,734.24 again
console.log($(totalCell).contents().eq(0).text());
```

It's probably something really stupid but I'm unable to see it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**
Here's the corresponding [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snhgn/1/). You'll need to check the console to test it properly.

Comment: Can you change the plugin code to put it in a div?

Comment: Also, does it change in the browser when you set the text, and jQuery is grabbing an older version, or does it not change anywhere at all?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Technically yes, but I would rather find out how this is done since it might come in handy. Besides, the plugin is a bit lengthy, so I would rather explore other options for now. Let me try to reproduce this in JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't seem to like changing text nodes. Hopefully somebody else can explain why, but the easiest way around it is to create a new text node, insert it, then remove the old one:

```
$(totalCell).contents().eq(0).before('Changed Forever').remove();
```

Of course this is more a workaround than a solution but should suffice for your needs, and it produces the same DOM structure (i.e. doesn't wrap it in span tags or similar)

Answer (score 2):

There's no great complexity to address this, simply replace the jQuery approach:

```
$(totalCell).contents().eq(0).text("VALUE HAS BEEN CHANGED FOREVER!");
```

With:

```
totalCell[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'value has been changed forever';
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Snhgn/3/).

Or if you want to stick with a 'more-jQuery' approach you could use:

```
totalCell.contents().eq(0).text(function(){
    return this.nodeValue = "VALUE HAS BEEN CHANGED FOREVER!";
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Snhgn/4/).

While jQuery doesn't make it *easy* to deal with setting the value of a `textNode`, it *is* possible to simply use native JavaScript to do so, hence the use of `nodeValue` in both of the above approaches. Rather than using a complex selector though, why not simply:

```
/* if you don't need to retain the jQuery methods of the selected node,
   I'd suggest using:
   $(".fht-cell").eq(0).get(0);
   omitted in this demo because I didn't know if you needed the jQuery methods */
var totalCell = $(".fht-cell").eq(0);

/* the `.get(0)` 'drops' the jQuery-wrapped node to a plain DOM node,
   allowing us to use native JavaScript traversal methods */
console.log("Before: " + totalCell.get(0).previousSibling.nodeValue);

// updating the nodeValue of the textNode:
totalCell.get(0).previousSibling.nodeValue = 'Value has been changed forever!';

console.log("After: " + totalCell.get(0).previousSibling.nodeValue);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Snhgn/5/).

Incidentally, given the following:

```
var totalCell = $("td.right.footerCell").eq(0);
```

`totalCell` is *already* a jQuery object, you don't need to re-wrap it with jQuery, therefore:

```
$(totalCell).contents().eq(0).text("VALUE HAS BEEN CHANGED FOREVER!");
```

Is *precisely* the same as:

```
totalCell.contents().eq(0).text("VALUE HAS BEEN CHANGED FOREVER!");
```

But the latter is a little more efficient/concise, JS Perf suggests [a slight (but *absolutely unnecessary*) performance-hit](http://jsperf.com/effects-of-re-wrapping-jquery-objects) in needlessly re-wrapping a jQuery object.

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/node.nodevalue).